# How to modify the return value of a member function with constant return type within another member function?

Tags: c++, oop

The title seems contradictory, and perhaps it is. But this is the problem I am trying to tackle in C++ 11.
I am creating a binary search tree, and the search functions looks something like this:

`const node* search(char);`

I have made the return type constant as I do not want the tree to be arbitrarily changed by outside functions(I am returning node* to allow traversals), but I am also using this function in the `remove()` function to find the node to be deleted. I want the returned value to be modifiable by the `remove()` member function.

The obvious solution seems to be: create a private search function with a non constant return type, but that seems to unnescessarily lengthen the code.

Is there another way to do this, or achieve a similar functionality?

Comment: You can do a `const_cast` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Depending of your `node` implementation, `delete(const node*)` might be valid.

Comment: BTW, I suggest to rename `delete` to avoid confusion with operator `delete`

Comment: @jarod42 the compiler ought to moan about that unless the op uses the operator keyword too.

Comment: How bout returning an iterator that `friend`s your class. Also abstracts the implementation away too, which is more "OOP"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this to avoid the code duplication:

```
class foo {
public:
    const node* search(char c) const { return internal_search(c); } 
private:
    node* internal_search(char c) const { 
        // actual implementation
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing, somewhat